# How make random number generator that excludes a specific value?

Tags: javascript

I'm going to make a function that makes a random number that isn't equal to a specified number.

```js
var number = 5;
var randnum2 = getrandnum(number);

function getrandnum(oldrandnum) {
  var results = Math.round(Math.random() * 7);
  if (results == oldrandnum) {
    getrandnum(oldrandnum);
  } else {
    return results;
  }
};

console.log(randnum2);
```

Explanation:

`getrandnum` is my function and it generates a random number that doesn't equal `5`.

My problem is that the results will be `NaN` some times.

Comment: Replace `getrandnum(oldrandnum);` with `return getrandnum(oldrandnum);`.

Comment: As you have not use `return` so it will not return any value till the end of the function and hence you will return `undefined`. Which you might be processing further and getting that NaN value.

Comment: oh thank you so much this my first question in stack overflow that i get the answer

Answer (score 1):

You should do `return getrandnum(oldrandnum);` instead of `getrandnum(oldrandnum);`

Comment: Well it won't return anything until the end of the function.